# C++: variable "long long" goes crazy when growing in loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a simple program in C++ for practice because I'm learning C++, so he program takes input number of for example 123 then it reverses that number in to 321 and adds it to its original number, than it reverses that number again and checks if it is same as if it was not reversed, if it is not the same process repeats until the reversed number is the same as non reversed number.

To my problem:
I have set up long long variables because in this calculations big numbers can show up, my problem is that when the number enters the loop(loop2) it seems to max out or something you can see result in screenshots.

NOTE: First while loop is not intended to repeat I placed code in it so that I can skip that code if you put in the number that already meets requirements.

NOTE2: I wrote this program in python exactly the same way and it works perfectly I can provide source for that also if it helps.

NOTE3: Don't mind text in strings, it is in my language.

NOTE4: In example I took screenshot from i typed number 196121 which should be solved in 4 steps   I tested it with my same program written in python.

[image]

```
/* while(number!=0){
reverse = reverse * 10;
reverse = reverse + number%10;
number = number/10;
}
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 1;
    int loop1 = 1;
    int loop2 = 1;
    long long num = 0ll;
    long long rev = 0ll;
    long long tmp = 0ll;
    long long tmp_ = 0ll;
    long long var_ = 0ll;
    long long zasprovj = 0ll;
    long long number = 0ll;

    cout << "UKOLIKO SE UNESE BROJ KOJI NIJE MOGUĆE IZRAČUNATI PROGRAM CE OSTATI    U BESKONACNOJ PETLJI KAO STO JE NPR. BROJ 196 !"<<endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "MOLIMO UNESITE BROJ: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;
    number = num;

    while (number != 0)
    {
        zasprovj = zasprovj * 10;
        zasprovj = zasprovj + number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }

    if (num == zasprovj)
    {
        cout << "Operacija izvrsena, rezultat:  " << zasprovj << "  Koraka = 0";
        loop1 = 0;
        loop2 = 0;
    }

    while (loop1 == 1)
    {
        number = num;
        while (number != 0)
        {
            rev = rev * 10;
            rev = rev + number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        cout << "okrenuti uneseni broj je: " << rev << endl;
        tmp = rev + num;
        cout << "rev + n = "<<tmp<<endl;
        number = tmp;
        while (number != 0)
        {
            tmp_ = tmp_ * 10;
            tmp_ = tmp_ + number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        cout << "okrenuti tmp = " << tmp_ << endl;

        if(tmp == tmp_)
        {
            cout << "Izracun je: " << tmp << "<-- u koraka: " << count << endl;
            loop2 = 0;
            loop1 = 0;
        }
        cout << ">>>>>>> "<<count<<". STEP <<<<<<"<<endl;
        loop1 = 0;
    }

    while (loop2 == 1)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        cout << ">>>>>>> " << count << ". STEP <<<<<<" << endl;

        number = tmp_;
        while(number!=0)
        {
            rev = rev * 10;
            rev = rev + number%10;
            number = number/10;
        }
        tmp = rev + tmp_;
        cout << "rev + tmp_ = "<<tmp<<endl;

        number = tmp;
        while (number != 0)
        {
            tmp_ = tmp_ * 10;
            tmp_ = tmp_ + number%10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        cout << "reversed tmp(tmp = rev + tmp_) = " << tmp_<<endl;

        if (tmp == tmp_)
        {
            cout << "Izracun je: "<<tmp<<"<-- u koraka: " <<count<<endl;
            loop2 = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "CTRL + C  za izlaz";
    cin >> rev;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue. Having such big wall of code, coupled with the fact that half of the variables (not to mention comments) aren't in English, makes very hard to understand what the code actually does.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reinitialize `rev` right before calculating the reverse.  So the old `rev` is prepended to the new reversed number.

Just add `rev = 0;` at the same time as `number = tmp_;`